# Tableview error in java

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Testtt{

    static List<String> products_list;
    static List<String> quantity_list;
    static List<String> selling_price_list; 
    static List<String> revenue_list;
    static List<String> cost_price_list; 
    static List<String> profit_margin_list; 
    static List<String> profit_list;


    public void TableView(Stage window){

        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
        AnchorPane top = new AnchorPane();
        layout.setTop(top);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 940, 630);

        Image Small_logo = new Image("file:Smaller_Logo.png"); 
        ImageView Small_logoView = new ImageView(Small_logo);
        Small_logoView.setFitWidth(100);
        Small_logoView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        Label title_message = new Label("Product sales");

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(title_message, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(Small_logoView, 5.0);
        top.getChildren().addAll(title_message,Small_logoView);

        VBox center = new VBox(10);
        center.setPadding(new Insets(20,10,0,10));

        products_list = Arrays.asList("Coffee", "Tea");
        quantity_list = Arrays.asList("5", "10");
        selling_price_list = Arrays.asList("10", "4");
        revenue_list = Arrays.asList("100", "120");
        cost_price_list = Arrays.asList("5", "2");
        profit_margin_list = Arrays.asList("50%", "5%");
        profit_list = Arrays.asList("25", "20");

        TableColumn<getting_data,String> products = new TableColumn<getting_data,String>("Product name");
        products.setMinWidth(180);
        products.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("product"));

        TableColumn<getting_data,String> quantity = new TableColumn<getting_data,String>("Quantity");
        quantity.setMinWidth(120);
        quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));

        TableColumn<getting_data,String> Selling_price_column = new TableColumn<getting_data,String>("Selling price");
        Selling_price_column.setMinWidth(160);
        Selling_price_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Selling_price"));

        TableColumn<getting_data,String> revenue_column = new TableColumn<getting_data,String>("Revenue");
        revenue_column.setMinWidth(120);
        revenue_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("revenue"));

        TableColumn<getting_data,String> cost_price_column = new TableColumn<getting_data,String>("Cost");
        cost_price_column.setMinWidth(80);
        cost_price_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cost"));

        TableColumn<getting_data,String> profit_column = new TableColumn<getting_data,String>("Profit");
        profit_column.setMinWidth(90);
        profit_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("profit"));

        TableColumn<getting_data,String> profit_margin_column = new TableColumn<getting_data,String>("Profit margin");
        profit_margin_column.setMinWidth(170);
        profit_margin_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("profit_margin"));

        TableView<getting_data> Table = new TableView<>();
        Table.setItems(load_products());
        Table.getColumns().addAll(products, quantity, Selling_price_column,revenue_column,cost_price_column,profit_column,profit_margin_column);

        center.getChildren().add(Table);
        layout.setCenter(center);

        HBox bottom_layout = new HBox(10);
        bottom_layout.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

        Button back = new Button("Go back to home screen");

        bottom_layout.getChildren().add(back);
        layout.setBottom(bottom_layout);

        scene.getStylesheets().add("Admin_style.css");

        window.setScene(scene);
    }

    public ObservableList<getting_data> load_products(){
        ObservableList<getting_data> products_observable_list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for(int i= 0;i<2;i++){
            products_observable_list.add(new getting_data(products_list.get(i),quantity_list.get(i),selling_price_list.get(i),revenue_list.get(i),cost_price_list.get(i),profit_list.get(i),profit_margin_list.get(i)));}
        return products_observable_list;}

    public class getting_data{

        private String product;
        private String quantity;
        private String Selling_price;
        private String revenue;
        private String cost;
        private String profit;
        private String profit_margin;

        public getting_data(String product,String quantity,String Selling_price,String revenue,String cost,String profit,String profit_margin){
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.product = product;
            this.Selling_price = Selling_price;
            this.revenue = revenue;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.profit = profit;
            this.profit_margin = profit_margin;}

        public String getProduct(){return product;}
        public void setProduct(String product){this.product=product;}

        public String getQuantity(){return quantity;}
        public void setQuantity(String quantity){this.quantity=quantity;}

        public String getSelling_price(){return Selling_price;}
        public void setSelling_price(String Selling_price){this.Selling_price=Selling_price;}

        public String getRevenue(){return revenue;}
        public void setRevenue(String revenue){this.revenue=revenue;}

        public String getCost(){return cost;}
        public void setCost(String cost){this.cost=cost;}

        public String getProfit(){return profit;}
        public void setProfit(String profit){this.profit=profit;}

        public String getMargin(){return profit_margin;}
        public void setMargin(String profit_margin){this.profit_margin=profit_margin;}

    }
    public static void passer(Stage window){
        Testtt function = new Testtt();
        function.TableView(window);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't display the value of the profit margin column not too sure why. I have checked if it was an issue with the string by placing the profit margin strings in other places and that displayed the correct values. I think it's probably an error in my getters and setter but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PropertyValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) uses the methods to get access to the property/the getter, not the field that this getter retrieves. (And how should it? The getter is not required to store the return value in a field.)

You have to use the correct name for the bean. Since your **field** is named `profit_margin`, but your **getter/setter** is named `getMargin`/`setMargin`, it should be

```
new PropertyValueFactory<>("margin")
```

instead of

```
new PropertyValueFactory<>("profit_margin")
```

Comment: Oh okay I was taught differently let me try that I was taught that the name of the variable in the getters and setters had to be defined there. Thanks